# Imacros if else error

Tags: if-statement, imacros

Hello stackoverflow i need you help with a script im trying to make.
The script im trying to make is a cointoss script that does the following.

The first part i want it to do is insert a amount i want to play with.

If i win insert same value as the first bet and set my datasource back to the first line.

If i loose use datasource to insert a new value and play again.

Here is what i came up with:

Cointoss.js

```
VERSION BUILD=8920312 RECORDER=FX

SET !DATASOURCE cointoss25.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}

if(iimPlay(WIN.iim)>0)
{
iimPlay(WINPLAY.iim)
}
else if(iimPlay(LOOSE.iim)>0)
{
iimPlay(LOOSEPLAY.iim)
}
```

WIN.iim Script

```
SEARCH SOURCE=TXT:"You guessed right! You win"
```

WINPLAY.iim Script

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:PLAY<SP>AGAIN
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:bet CONTENT=25
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.paidverts.com/assets/images/games/coin_flip/heads.gif
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
```

LOOSE.iim Script

```
SEARCH SOURCE=TXT:"You guessed wrong. Try again!"
```

LOOSEPLAY.iim Script

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:PLAY<SP>AGAIN
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:bet CONTENT={{!COL1}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.paidverts.com/assets/images/games/coin_flip/heads.gif
```

The problem is i keep getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement, line NaN (Error code: -991)
```

Comment: Pay attention to the fact that in ‘Cointoss.js’ you’ve got an iim-code. So, in this js-script use the `iimPlayCode(...)` function for running it and a loop to read your csv-file.

Comment: Im not that experienced with imacros, but how would i go about with the loop?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the variant of ‘Cointoss.js’ like this:

```
var M;
const L = "\n";
var maxLoop = 5;    // your value here

for (loop = 1; loop <= maxLoop; loop++) {
    M = "SET !DATASOURCE cointoss25.csv" + L;
    M += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE " + loop + L;
    iimPlayCode(M);

    if (iimPlay(WIN.iim) > 0)
        iimPlay(WINPLAY.iim);
    else if (iimPlay(LOOSE.iim) > 0)
        iimPlay(LOOSEPLAY.iim);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It helped me quite a bit, but still had to change up alot (Into one script file)

Now i got some problems with inserting the data from datasource, it doesn't seems to work.

```
var MaxLoops = 50;
var TossLoop;
var HeadsIMG;
var TailsIMG;
var StartIMG;

HeadsIMG = "IMAGESEARCH POS=1 IMAGE=Heads.png CONFIDENCE=95 \n";
TailsIMG = "IMAGESEARCH POS=1 IMAGE=Tails.png CONFIDENCE=95 \n";
StartIMG = "IMAGESEARCH POS=1 IMAGE=Start.png CONFIDENCE=95 \n";

FirstPlay = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:bet CONTENT=25 EXTRACT=TXT \n";
FirstPlay += "WAIT SECONDS=4 \n";
FirstPlay += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.paidverts.com/assets/images/games/coin_flip/heads.gif \n";
FirstPlay += "WAIT SECONDS=4 \n";
FirstPlay += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1 \n";

WinPlay = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:PLAY<SP>AGAIN \n";
WinPlay += "WAIT SECONDS=4 \n";
WinPlay += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:bet CONTENT=25 EXTRACT=TXT \n";
WinPlay += "WAIT SECONDS=4 \n";
WinPlay += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.paidverts.com/assets/images/games/coin_flip/heads.gif \n";
WinPlay += "WAIT SECONDS=4 \n";
WinPlay += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1 \n";

LoosePlay = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:PLAY<SP>AGAIN \n";
LoosePlay += "WAIT SECONDS=4 \n";
LoosePlay += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT ATTR=ID:bet CONTENT={{!COL1}} \n";
LoosePlay += "WAIT SECONDS=4 \n";
LoosePlay += "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=SRC:http://www.paidverts.com/assets/images/games/coin_flip/heads.gif \n";

for (loop = 1; loop <= MaxLoops; loop++) {
    TossLoop = "SET !DATASOURCE CoinToss25.csv" + "\n";
    TossLoop += "SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 1" + "\n";
    TossLoop += "SET !DATASOURCE_LINE " + loop + "\n";

    iimPlayCode(TossLoop);
    if (iimPlayCode(StartIMG) > 0)
        iimPlayCode(FirstPlay);
    else if (iimPlayCode(HeadsIMG) > 0)
        iimPlayCode(WinPlay);
    else if (iimPlayCode(TailsIMG) > 0)
        iimPlayCode(LoosePlay);
}
```